# MissingEndpoint error when attempting to publish to IoT core from a Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, serverless

I have a Lambda and I'm attempting to publish to an IoT core via the SDK. However I'm getting an error

```
{
    "errorMessage": "MissingEndpoint: 'Endpoint' configuration is required for this service",
    "errorType": "baseError"
}
```

Here's my publish function:

```
func publish() error {
    session := session.New(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("eu-west-2"),
    })
    iot := iotdataplane.New(session)
    input := &iotdataplane.PublishInput{
        Payload: []byte("take picture"),
        Topic:   aws.String("take-picture"),
    }
    resp, err := iot.Publish(input)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Here are some IAM/roles stuff I've added as part of my serverless config:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: go1.x
  region: eu-west-1
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "iot:Publish"
      Resource: ["arn:aws:iot:eu-west-2:<redacted>:thing/mini-camera"]
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "iot:Connect"
      Resource: ["*"]
```

Comment: You probably already concluded that `'Endpoint' configuration is required for this service` seems to imply that `aws.Config { Endpoint: ...` is expected.  Intuition suggests that this *might* mean you are using an SDK version that predates the availability of this service in this region.  Probably unrelated, you have `eu-west-1` rather than `eu-west-2` in your role config.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot that was absolutely it, thank you!

Comment: I guess I managed to make about 3 different suggestions... which one was it?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot ahh yes, it was the missing Endpoint url from the config struct. I added the Endpoint generated in the IoT console for my device